# How Zeus became king of the gods?

Tags: greek

Zeus is King of Gods.

> God of the sky, lightning, thunder, law, order, and justice

but how and why? Why he is called King of all gods? Which made him king and what were those factors that he was picked or became King of Gods.

Answer (score 7):

Zeus, his siblings, and his allies overthrew his father Kronos, who had eaten his siblings in an attempt to thwart the prophecy which said that one of his children would overthrow him.

When all was said and done, Zeus and his brothers Poseidon and Hades drew lots or threw dice or executed some other game of chance to see who would rule what part of the world. Zeus won, making him king. He chose the sky to rule. Poseidon was second, and chose the sea; Hades, getting the leftovers, was given the underworld.

Sources: [Theoi's article on Zeus,](http://www.theoi.com/Olympios/Zeus.html) which attributes the myth to Homer's [*Iliad* xv. 187](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134%3Abook%3D15%3Acard%3D184), &c., i. 528, ii. 111; and Virgil's [*Aeneid* iv. 372](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D362).

Comment: I am not so sure about the drawing of lots part. The versions i recall, he chose the heavens to rule, then granted posideon the sea, and hades what was left. Then again the thing about greek mythology and mythology in general is that there are contradictions in the lore between different locations.  I could pose reasons to why that is, specifically in polytheistic faiths but thats not important.

Comment: @anon the casting of the lots comes from [Apollodorus, Library, 1.2.1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0022%3Atext%3DLibrary%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D2%3Asection%3D1) *"but they [the three brothers] themselves cast lots for the sovereignty, and to Zeus was allotted the dominion of the sky, to Poseidon the dominion of the sea, and to Pluto the dominion in Hades."*

Answer (score 3):

The most probable antroposophical reason for a shift from the earth god to the sky god is that the earth god provided humans with the produce of nature up until the invention and rise of agriculture. The earth was under the influence of the elements and the sky became more important in agriculture for timing and time keeping in relation to sowing, harvesting and threshing the grains.

Comment: It may also have a male/female component.  Ouranos vs. Gaia (although, we all know who came out ahead in that conflict;)